# Computer shuts down instantly every 2 hours and 1 minute

Tags: shutdown, touchsmart

I have a [HP Touchsmart 600-1155](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-TouchSmart-600-Desktop-PC-series/4079692/model/4176686) All-In-One computer and recently has started to power off by himself (like long pressing on power button) every 2 hours 1 minute and few seconds (on the clock).
I have never overclocked it and no drivers or devices was installed recently (os it`s out of scheme because it happens in bios too).

What i have tried so far:

1. Checked temperatures (all ok)
2. Checked voltages (all ok)
3. Ran hp diagnostics (a tool that can be started at boot)
4. Reset cmos
5. Checked windows logs (nothing relevant. also OS is not relevant because it happens even in bios).
6. Replace thermal paste on CPU and Video
7. Checked all fans/coolers
8. Reseat various components like hdd, dvd, minicards etc. (read somewhere that this action can do magic sometimes :) )

Also i cannot run memtest properly because the 2 hours timeframe but the hp tool says there is no problem.

I am aware that can be the PSU and i cannot replace it right now but i cannot explain why 2h 1 minute every time... even if i power it on immediately and do a stress test on him.

If you have an idea i am open to test it :)

Thanks,

Comment: Please try troubleshooting discussed here: http://superuser.com/questions/170374/troubleshooting-new-computer-shuts-down-instantly

Comment: +1 for consistent gender assignment and **thorough** diagnostics. If there's anything I've learned in 3+ years of diagnosing computers it's that AIO's have a notorious reputation for overheating. **especially** in HP's, I couldn't stress this enough. The fact that it's occurring **outside** of OS is a substantial contributor to the process of elimination. So it's not software, it's hardware. I highly doubt it's the PS, in my experience a faulty PS has much different symptoms. My prognosis? There's a heating/cooling issue going on. What kind of CPU are you running?

Comment: P.S. Kudos for disassembling and replacing thermal paste, that's a time consuming process across the board. Do I have an idea to test? Probably, I just have to think on it. You've stumped me with your "complete" series of tests and that's saying **alot**, believe me. Update the BIOS? The bizarre 2 hrs & 1 minute issue might be some weird firmware (BIOS) issue. Then again, the CPU might also be overheating at that point and the eta's might be subject to "human" error. :P No harm intended.

Comment: @BiTinerary The CPU is [Intel Core i7 720QM](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-TouchSmart-600-Desktop-PC-series/4079692/model/4176686/document/c02059296/) . I cannot find bios upgrades from the hp website.

Comment: Also the 2h 1 minute is pretty exact because when i work on it i setup an alarm on my watch to remember to save everything before it goes down :)